# How to query for matches between users in cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a following collections

```
-likes (collection)
  -{uid} (document)
   {otheruserUID: true, anotherUID: true ...}
-likedBy (collection)
  -{uid} (document)
   {otheruserUID: true, anotherUID: true ...}
```

A user can like other users. What I want to query for is given a user, query for all matches of that user. Should I query whole likes and likedby data and run match in result and produce match results? Is there any other easy way to do this? Or may be better way to model the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would simply have a single collection, called `likes`.  Each like generates a new document with an auto-id and contains 3 fields: `user` (an object containing the `id` and `name` of the user), `likedBy` (an object containing the `id` and `name` of the user who liked them) and `timestamp` (when they were liked).

You'll be able to carry out the following queries:

```
// Find all users who liked likedUser, sorted by user
db.collection('likes').where('likedBy.name', '!=', null).where('user.id', '==', likedUser).orderBy('likedBy.name');

// Find all users who were liked by likedByUser, sorted by user
db.collection('likes').where('user.name', '!=', null).where('likedBy.id', '==', likedByUser).orderBy('user.name');
```

The first time that you run these queries, you will get an error, telling you to create an index.  This error will include the URL to create the index for you.

The first `where` is required to allow the `orderBy` to work, see the documentation section [Range filter and orderBy on the same field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data)

Comment: still confused on how to get users who liked each other