# Modeling Firestore Structure with Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

### How can I structure this with Firestore and Angular?

In a JSON Cloud Firestore database, I need to insert people.

These people will be related to a user, so I need to make a node.

How to make a node so that the query in the bank is fast and efficient?

I think it would not be correct to save all people in a single collection because the query would be time consuming.

**user1**: // people related to this user

**personList**:

**2 people registered**

```
[{'name': 'person 1'}, {'name': 'person 2'}]
```

---

**user2:** // people related to this user

**personList**:

**3 people registered**

```
[{'name': 'another person 1'}, {'name': 'another person 2'}, {'name': 'another person 3'}]
```

If I register 10 **people** with **user1**, if I am logged in to the system with **user1** it should only list **people** related to **user1**.

Comment: at the moment I'm just saving people and logging in with the user, but I need to list only the people of each user and not all the people that are registered.

Comment: Are people themselves users?

Comment: If you can provide some current code that shows how a `user` is structured and how a `person` is structured, I am sure we could figure something out

Comment: I am authenticating to the system with the Firebase authentication service.

Each user will have their people registered.

At the moment I'm inserting people for all users, but each user will have the people who registered.

Comment: @hlfrmn I've added more information, see if you can understand what I need

Comment: It depends how you want to query your data.  If you are only interested in a user seeing related people, then I would suggest storing these people in a `personList` sub-collection of each user doc.  If you need to query to find all users related to a person, then you'll need to look at using [Maps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays#solution_a_map_of_values) to allow them to be indexed.

Comment: @JasonBerryman 
Thanks, I was able to relate people to each user so that the query is quick.

Comment: Which method did you use?

Comment: If you need to keep data synced across multiple users / people, have a look at these 2 posts: [Best way to structure related data in firebase/firestore and manage updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668823/best-way-to-structure-related-data-in-firebase-firestore-and-manage-updates/48688237) and [How to query for matches between users in cloud firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48618612/how-to-query-for-matches-between-users-in-cloud-firestore)

Comment: @JasonBerryman I've been checking some firebase structure concepts and got where I needed it, it was exactly in the source of information that you gave me that I did what I needed, thank you!

Comment: Great.  Glad to help.  If you don't mind, I'll post that as an answer and "hopefully" you can marked it as answered so I can build up my score :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you want to query your data. If you are only interested in a user seeing related people, then I would suggest storing these people in a personList sub-collection of each user doc. If you need to query to find all users related to a person, then you'll need to look at using [Maps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays#solution_a_map_of_values) to allow them to be indexed

If you need to keep data synced across multiple users / people, have a look at these 2 posts: [Best way to structure related data in firebase/firestore and manage updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668823/best-way-to-structure-related-data-in-firebase-firestore-and-manage-updates/48688237) and [How to query for matches between users in cloud firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48618612/how-to-query-for-matches-between-users-in-cloud-firestore)